# How to specify query result location in another aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I want to run an Athena query from the console in account A. I want to specify the query result location to be an s3 bucket in account B. How can this be done? I tried specifying the target account id when setting the query result location but I still got an error that "Unable to verify/create output bucket ". I also tried creating IAM roles in both the target account and in the source account and still got this issue.

Comment: Did you add a Bucket Policy on the bucket in Account-B that allows connection from Athena in Account-A? I'm not sure what the policy would need to provide but you could temporarily start with an "Allow Everything to Everybody" policy just to see whether the error goes away. IAM Roles are irrelevant because Athena will not assume the roles you created.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein "IAM Roles are irrelevant because Athena will not assume the roles you created." True, but since I am running from the console, shouldn't the permissions be based on the role I am logged in with? I added a policy to the Admin role in Account A that allows it to assume a role in account B. In account B, I said that account A is allowed to assume a role in B and that role has full S3 access. 

I did not try adding a bucket policy though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Athena queries will **use the permissions of the user who made the request**. Athena will not assume any additional roles.

Therefore, the IAM entity that is making the request (which in your case seems to be an IAM Role) will need permission to `PutObject` in the Account-B bucket.

In addition, since this is a cross-account activity, **the S3 bucket in Account-B will *also* need a Bucket Policy** that permits `PutObject` from the same IAM entity.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was missing a bucket policy, also I was logged in as an assumed role user (or federated user, not entirely sure), so I needed to update the principal ARN to reflect that